# 3 x 3 HTML structure

Tags: javascript, css, html, styles

I want to make a grid 3x3, but problem is that the height on some of the cells will expand with content.

Apart from those height marked with the red arrows, the rest is fixed px.

I made a 3x3 grid with divs to test:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="one">1</div> <div id="two">2</div> <div id="three">3</div>
<div id="four">4</div> <div id="five">5</div> <div id="six">6</div>
<div id="seven">7</div> <div id="eight">8</div> <div id="nine">9</div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px; 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But as soon as I change one height they jump out of place.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with javascript

Comment: @Joren I though I may have to use JS to calc grid position in runtime or something, thats why I used that tag.

Comment: What content are you putting in these?  Text, image, other block elements?

Comment: I don’t understand. Do you want a grid or not?

Comment: @Deryck The cells that will expand will have one table each that can have as many rows as users want to add, it will be dinamic

Comment: @minitech I want exactly whats on my draw. The height of those cells with red arrows may vary

Comment: That’s… not a grid at all. Does it have to be in rows? (Because what you appear to be looking for are columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you want columns.

A structure like this:

```
<div class="column-thing">
    <div class="left-thing">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-thing">
        <div>B<br>B</div>
        <div>D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some absolute positioning:

```css
.column-thing {
    position: relative;
}

.left-thing {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}

.right-thing {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Voilà.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/dZg6U/)

Comment: Can you place a third column?

Comment: The correct 3x3 answer by @minitech is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/dZg6U/2/) and on his comment above, not in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lists (ul/ol, li) (without javascript)

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><div>1<br/>1</div></li>
            <li><div>2</div></li>
            <li><div>3</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKjNG/

Comment: This seems to be a solution. Although it seems weird to use lists :) But I'll give it a go. If it works I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that there's three divs in each row, you need to ensure that there's actually a div enclosing each set of three divs...

Comment: Even if I do that, it stays the same. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sa4UE/1/ It still breaks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px; 0px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.clear_float {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<div id="one">1</div> <div id="two">2</div> <div id="three">3</div><div class = "clear_float"></div>
<div id="four">4</div> <div id="five">5</div> <div id="six">6</div><div class = "clear_float"></div>
<div id="seven">7</div> <div id="eight">8</div> <div id="nine">9</div><div class = "clear_float"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nop, same problem has others (http://jsfiddle.net/q7bVm/). Like minitech said, better to think columns and not rows

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly.

You want only 1 3 6 and 9 to be able to change their height and the rest to have fixed size?

Answer (score -1):

I'm taking it that the content shouldn't be table based which is why you don't want to use a table.
But an idea would be to use a faux table:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
    </div>
    <div class="td">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then on .table add CSS *display:table* and  on .td add CSS *display:table-cell*.

The naming convention helps work with the code because you'll be used to working with a table's tags structure.

I made a quick example (needed more work than I thought it would): http://jsfiddle.net/cyv6y/1/

needs tidying up a bit but the concept works.

Comment: I'm not using tables, because the td height will adapt to the biggest td height in same row. Same will happen with your solution.

Comment: Just seen your update. On your example 8 should be close to 5 and 9 to 6. Like in my draw.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Fiddle? I though you wanted the rows to expand?

Comment: He wants them all equal sizes

Comment: Yes missed that out, needs some divs with fixed height/width. I'll update my test.

Comment: Not sure I get it so aplogoes if it's not helpful but this was what I was thinking: http://jsfiddle.net/arroni/N2D4T/